# I am converting latlong to string to find direction between two places. so i am getting this URL

Tags: android

so i am getting this URL.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?&origin=lat%2Flng%3A+%2853.25607629079481%2C93.87487169355153%29&destination=lat%2Flng%3A+%2842.293994729102494%2C107.57313340902328%29&sensor=false&mode=driving&key=AIzaSyATs_vOy7Qths4ErsfalVYNNjWAoeiiS50

which gives me this wrong answer.. 
the value of string i am getting is this

lat/lng: (53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153)

how to trim this value to this

53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153

Comment: what is your actual question?

Comment: i want to trim this value" lat/lng: (53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153) "to this "53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153" ... i am passing this latlong value directly to url

Answer (score 0):

The lat/lng you have are in `double`. So, what you need to do is, first change the double values to `String` like this:

```
 String Slat = String.valueOf(YourDoubleValue);
 String Slng = String.valueOf(YourDoubleValue);
```

and then pass these Strings to the url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the following string:

```
lat/lng: (53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153)
```

to the following:-

```
53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153
```

Then, you can do the following:

```
String input="lat/lng: (53.25607629079481,93.87487169355153)";
input = input.split("\\s+")[1]  // split the string by space
System.out.println(input.substring(1, input.length()-1));
```